# Upgrade RDS to new instance type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a db.m3.large RDS MySQL instance in us-west-2 w/ multi-AZ that we need to upgrade to a larger instance type (and would like to move to current generation, as well).  However, for the last 2 days we can't upgrade to either db.m4.xlarge nor db.m4.2xlarge; when we try (through the console) we get:

> Cannot modify the instance class because there are not enough
>   availability zones that have the requested instance class. Please try
>   your request again at a later time. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code:
>   400; Error Code: InsufficientDBInstanceCapacity; Request ID:
>   a1f7a557-0bbb-11e6-bf10-e7d51b83a4d4)

I know this maybe just be that AWS doesn't have capacity there, but given that it's been the case for 2 days now...

I've also wondered if maybe we drop multi-AZ we might be able to upgrade and then re-enable multi-AZ, but that's sort of grasping at straws.

(and I know this may be too much of a `support` question for serverfault, but I figure it doesn't hurt to ask...)

Comment: What region are you deployed to?

Comment: us-west-2 region

Answer (score 2):

I think is this likely because our `db.m3` is not in a VPC, and `db.m4` instances are required to be in a VPC.

Answer (score 0):

in Multi AZ- can you specify what zones because those flavors are not available in all zones.

> The following list describes the current Amazon RDS DB instance
>   classes and the Amazon EC2 instance type used for each:
>
> Standard – Latest Generation (db.m4) – Third generation instances that
>   provide more computing capacity than the second generation db.m3
>   instance classes at a lower price. This DB instance class requires
>   that the DB instance be in a VPC. Note Multi-AZ deployments using
>   db.m4 instance classes are not available in the Asia Pacific (Sydney)
>   region. The db.m4 instance classes are not available for the South
>   America (São Paulo) or China (Beijing) regions.

Comment: us-west-2 region.

Comment: multi Availability Zone?

Comment: Yes, it is multi-AZ.

Comment: you know what that means? - if an AWS AZ has a service interruption it moves your RDS to another AZ based on a load balancing algorithm - it's telling you it can't maintain a multi AZ configuration because "there are not enough availability zones that have the requested instance class" - please see my earlier answer.

Comment: Actually, I think it's the requirement that `db.m4` instances be in a VPC.  Our existing `db.m3` isn't.

Comment: it's in a default VPC - and if it had anything to do with not being in a VPC then that is what the error would say